# SQL Script creation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am learning SQL and using SQL Developer. I am supposed to use the scripts to type all the code but in developer all I see are the SQL worksheets. How do I create a script file from SQL Developer?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS? is that MS-Access?

Comment: If Access, there should be a little SQL icon somewhere that lets you get from design mode to a window where you can type in SQL.

Comment: With sql developer, it's probably oracle.

Comment: Yes it is Oracle... anyone know how to do it on Oracle sql developer?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to "Save As" and save the file.  If that's not what you want, I'm not sure what "use the scripts" means in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL worksheet *is* the method by which you build SQL scripts in SQL Developer. Once you have written your script, use File -> Save As to save the script to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate sql-script for export objects you can do so as shown below. For example will show how to make a script to export the table -

[image]

then you can choose the settings (export with data or not, include grants/schema name etc.) -

[image]

Comment: Nice tip but this doesn't answer the question.